# Making a circular fade to transparent with nodes

Tags: materials, node-editor, lighting

So I have made my y axis of this plane 'fade' to transparent ... 
[image]

any idea how I can set up some nodes to make it start fading from the blue circle and then be fully transparent by the time it reaches the red circle?
[image]

I have been trying a lot of different setups but can't seem to make a circular fade work

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a simple circle (spherical)gradient, to control the transparency. Here a simple basic set up.You could add a math node before the ramp to control it, if the texture coordinate node is not enough.The texture could be, also,connected in the object space of the sphere,to let the transparency follow the object around[image]

Comment: I guess you might also add that the texture can be put in the object space of the sphere, if @Cameron wants the transparency to follow the sphere around...

Comment: @Robin Betts .Yes, edited and added your suggestion, thanks.

Comment: Genius .... really great answer and exactly what I was looking for!!! 

- Deep appreciation from Deutschland!