# How to make a texture follow the object? Gradient circle

Tags: texturing

I am following [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158518/making-a-circular-fade-to-transparent-with-nodes) other thread, but the texture does not follow the object. They say something about "connected in the object space of the sphere" but I don't have any idea of how to do that. Any help?

Here I show a picture of my problem. I want the gradient to follow the circles.

[image]

Here I show my nodes
[image]

Is there any easier way to do a color gradient?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: hello, could you please show a picture of what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all three of those circles are part of the same object, blender is using the "midpoint" of all of them as the 0,0,0 point. If you want each of them to have the gradient in the center, they must be separate objects for this material setup to work properly. *Object* texture coordinate uses the center of the object as the 0,0,0 "grid point".

Here is an example using your same material setup - Start by selecting a whole circle by selecting any vertex on it and then pressing <kbd>L</kbd> while your mouse is over it. Once it is selected, press <kbd>P</kbd> (separate) and choose "by selection".

[image: Setup]

Once they are separated, they will each still have their origins at the same place they were before the separation - likely the midpoint of the three circles. To fix this, select each object (one by one) and select "Set origin to Geometry" from the menu at the top (pictured below). This will reset the 0,0,0 grid point back to the center of each circle.

[image: Separate]